# Beautiful soup/requests not fetching the value

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

OBJECTIVE : To fetch values which are updated periodically on this [website](https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_market.htm)

The wanted values/numbers are like this on the website :

```
Advances -  1089    Declines -  708 Unchanged - 80  Total - 1877
```

I used `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to read html and get those numbers. But there is a problem. When I open the page in a web browser and 'inspect element' I get this :

```
<td style="border-right: 1px solid #ACA99F;width:82px;color:green;font-size:1.2em;">1089</td>
```

You see that line contains the data I want i.e `>1089<`. But When I run my python scraping code `requests` does not return these numbers. Instead I get a `>-<` !

```
<tr>
<td>Advances - </td>
<td style="border-right: 1px solid 
#ACA99F;width:82px;color:green;font-size:1.2em;">-</td>
<td style="padding-left:8px;">Declines - </td>
<td style="border-right: 1px solid #ACA99F;width:82px;color:red;font-
size:1.2em;">-</td>
<td style="padding-left:8px">Unchanged - </td>
<td style="border-right: 1px solid #ACA99F;width:82px;font-
size:1.2em;">-</td>
<td style="padding-left:8px">Total - </td> 
<td style="width:82px;text-align:right;font-size:1.2em;">-</td>
</tr>
</table>]
```

The code I executed was :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Base_url = 
("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_market.htm")

page = requests.get(Base_url)
page.status_code
page.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

ti=soup.find_all(class_= "mkt_content")
tc=soup.find_all(id = "advanceDecline")

print(tc)
```

What mistake is happening and where. I think the problem is occurring in `requests` and not `Beautiful Soup`. Please elaborate as this is the first  time I am working with HTML/scraping.If any additional information is needed, please ask in the comments I will provide.

Comment: You didn't make any mistake p699. The numbers you want are not present in the data sent by the server. They are instead added by JavaScript after the page is loaded. I'd use @drec4s' answer below. More generally though, you could use Selenium with Python to get the content produced by JavaScript if you couldn't query the target site's API directly...

Comment: @duhaime Yep, the server wasnt sending the data. Now I know why. And Selenium seems to be quite powerful.Thanks, I used drec4s answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That occurs because the content is dynamically generated via JavaScript. However, you can get those values by querying their API via:

```
import requests
import json


URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/changePercentage.json"

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
    resp = s.get(URL).json()
    if resp['success']:
        print(resp['rows'][0]['advances'])
        print(resp['rows'][0]['declines'])
        print(resp['rows'][0]['unchanged'])
        print(resp['rows'][0]['total'])
```

**Outputs:**

```
1089
708
80
1877
```

Comment: It worked easily. It also taught me what to see in a webpage next time. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium` to better emulate a browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_market.htm')
#now, inspection of the source shows the correct values are listed
s = ' '.join([i.text for i in soup(d.page_source, 'lxml').find_all('td')][:8])
```

Output:

```
u'Advances -  1089 Declines -  708 Unchanged -  80 Total -  1877'
```

Comment: Never tried Selenium but it seems to be a very powerful tool.I did not test your code but I know I will be needing it soon. For now I chose drec4s answer but  I appreciate your effort to help me out. Thanks a ton sir.

Comment: @p699 Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [`Requests-HTML`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html):

**Code:**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_market.htm')
r.html.render()
result = r.html.find('#advanceDecline', first=True).text.replace('\n', ' ')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Advances - 1089 Declines - 708 Unchanged - 80 Total - 1877
```

Comment: Thanks for you help sir. I will implement your code in another part of my project. Thanks for your time, I appreciate it very much.